# what is wrong with my curl to romaji.org?

Tags: php, curl

charset set on the page to curl is Shift_JIS and lang set to jp

```
    function jp_new ($jp_text) 
{
// Begin Curl
$session = curl_init();
//$url1 = "http://nihongo.j-talk.com/index.php";
$url1 = "http://www.romaji.org/index.php";
$parameters = '&text='.urlencode($jp_text).'&save=convert+text+to+Romaji';
$header = array(
"Accept-Language: jp",
"Accept-Charset: Shift_JIS");
// $header[] = "Accept-Language: ja"; 
//$parameters = 'kanji='.urlencode($jp_text).'&converter=spaced&Submit=Translate+Now';
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
$jp_page = curl_exec($session); 
curl_close($session);

//$pattern = "/romaji'>(.+?)</s";
$pattern = "/color=\"red\">(.+?)</s";
preg_match_all ($pattern, $jp_page, $result_ro);
return $result_ro[1];

}
```

i get a result but its messed up and not the same result i would get if i submited the form from romaji.com manually. result i get when jptext = "犬猫"　is "kou (kigou)(kigou) shin i"

im sure the preg match only will find one match and its finding it in the right place. but it seems like some sort of encoding problem, but idk really.

a similar curl worked for "http://nihongo.j-talk.com/index.php" (the commented out variables) but it seems they have banned me so i need to adapt it to work for this new url romaji.org

UPDATE:
the charset on the romaji.org page is Shift_JIS, and my page is UTF-8 so i tried adding the curlopt header to the curl as in the code example now, the result in the output differed little, one of the words in brackets was removed, result is still messed up.

Comment: Have you tried sending "Accept-Charset" and "Accept-Language" headers? Check the headers from your browser, and simulate them.

Comment: no i have not, how do i do that?

Comment: Added as an answer as a bit long/complex for comments. Also note that you're not POSTING the value - but that may be irrelevent.

Comment: First of all, dump the `$jp_page` into the file and see what's there. Maybe they show you the captcha or an error with your form submit. Second, I don't see where you visit the page with the form before submit. That's important for session and cookie handling (use same curl resource for doing both requests).

Comment: i did that, they jpage has the strange text in the place i would find the real answer if i were to submit manually, no receptcha, it shows as if everything finished fine, but the result is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Simple Conversion would do the trick

```
$jp_text = iconv('UTF-8','Shift_JIS' , $jp_text);
```

Or

```
$jp_text = mb_convert_encoding($jp_text, "Shift_JIS", "UTF-8");
```

If you run

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = "犬猫";
var_dump(jp_new($str));
```

Output

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'inuneko' (length=7)
```

[Online Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1xPt5X)

Modified Function

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = "犬猫";
var_dump(jp_new($str));

function jp_new($jp_text) {
    $session = curl_init();
    $url1 = "http://www.romaji.org/index.php";
    //$jp_text = iconv('UTF-8','Shift_JIS' , $jp_text);
    $jp_text = mb_convert_encoding($jp_text, "Shift_JIS", "UTF-8");
    $parameters = '&text=' . urlencode($jp_text) . '&save=convert+text+to+Romaji';
    $header = array(
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
            "Referer: http://www.romaji.org/index.php",
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    $jp_page = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    // $pattern = "/romaji'>(.+?)</s";
    $pattern = "/color=\"red\">(.+?)</s";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $jp_page, $result_ro);
    return $result_ro[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get different results from browser to script, your aim is to simulate the same data send by the browser. What usually differs are the "headers", including cookies.

**Part 1: trapping the headers**

1. You can use the netwrok monitoring tools of various browsers (press F12 in Chrome / IE, or install Firebug and find the network monitors). Start logging and check the requests sent. Specifically, look for the headers.
2. You may find this easier with "[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/)"
3. Check for any headers, and any cookies send with the request. If a cookie, you may need to go backwards and work out how hte cookie got there, but for now, you cna hard code it.

**Part 2: sending headers**

In you case, it's probably the "Accept-Charset" and "Accept-Language" headers. You can speify these with

```
$headers = array(
    "Accept-Language: en-us",
    "Accept-Charset: utf-8");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

If you need other headers, add to the array. If you need cookies, [follow the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) or google other examples.

NOTE: I notice that you also set "POSTFIELDS" but don' actually specify you're sending a POST. Add the following if you want to send as a POST:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

Comment: i tried this, i doesnt seem to effect the result. i noticed that the romaji.org page specifies the encoding as Shift_JIS. does this mean i should be accept-charset Shift_JIS?

Comment: also, he sets his html tag with a lang="ja"

Comment: Yes - edit my example and COPY the headers. All of them - add more if you have more. (I can't give you the solution exactly as you know what you're doing and can read the headers - I can only give you the method to get the solution!)

Comment: the only line he has is <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">

Comment: i tried doing "Accept-Charset: Shift_JIS" that didnt effect the output either though

Comment: The <meta-equv> is in the HTML - you're looking in the wrong place as those are not the HTTP headers (trapped by Fiddler ot the network monitoris) and they are sent FROM the server, not sent by your browser to the server. Don't confuse the HTML HEAD (in the source code - not what you want) with the HTTP headers sent by the browser to the server.

Comment: so where do i find the http headers? im not following you